# Powerquery, sorting grouped rows with a parent column with grouped value in another column

Tags: sorting, powerquery

I'm unsure how to approach this complex problem, I need to sort a table by a group key, but each said group has a parent row which is identified by the group key in another column.

So with this example,

| sku | parentsku |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | null |
| 200-1 | 200 |
| 200-2 | 200 |
| 103 | null |
| xxx | 103 |
| yyy1 | 103 |
| yyy3 | 103 |
| 400 | null |
| 600 | null |
| 601 | 600 |
| 602 | 600 |
| 405 | 400 |

I'd need to get

| sku | parentsku |
| --- | --- |
| 103 | null |
| xxx | 103 |
| yyy1 | 103 |
| yyy3 | 103 |
| 200 | null |
| 200-1 | 200 |
| 200-2 | 200 |
| 400 | null |
| 405 | 400 |
| 600 | null |
| 601 | 600 |
| 602 | 600 |

There is no guarantee that the rows are in any pattern close together right now.

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to use `Table.Sort` and supply a custom function for the `comparisonCriteria` parameter that sorts the rows as such:

1. primarily by SKU (determined dynamically during comparison)
2. secondarily by whether the `parentsku` column was `null`
3. thirdly by the `sku` column

The code below attempts to do what's described above:

```
let
    initialTable = Table.FromRows({
        {"200", null},
        {"200-1", "200"},
        {"200-2", "200"},
        {"103", null},
        {"xxx", "103"},
        {"yyy1", "103"},
        {"yyy3", "103"},
        {"400", null},
        {"600", null},
        {"601", "600"},
        {"602", "600"},
        {"405", "400"}
    }, type table [sku = text, parentsku = text]),
    // Custom sorting behaviour to sort by SKU. If SKUs are equal (for two rows), preference should be given to rows containing a null parent SKU.
    sorted = Table.Sort(initialTable, (x as record, y as record) => 
        let
            xSku = if null <> x[parentsku] then x[parentsku] else x[sku],
            ySku = if null <> y[parentsku] then y[parentsku] else y[sku],
            skusComparison = Value.Compare(xSku, ySku),
            skusAreNotEqual = 0 <> skusComparison,
            parentComparison = if null = x[parentsku] then -1 else if null = y[parentsku] then 1 else Value.Compare(x[sku], y[sku]),
            sorted = if skusAreNotEqual then skusComparison else parentComparison
        in sorted
    )
in
    sorted
```

and produces a table like:

[image: Output]

which I believe matches your expected output.

Comment: This looks very promising, I am trying to understand how it works.... so I see x and y records are two function parameters.... but what is filling them with records?   How did you know the table.sort function would provide them?  Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @J.M.Becker, the `comparisonCriteria` parameter for sorting functions can take various forms, one of which is a function (like the one used here). To see details about `comparisonCriteria`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-sort#about. The link is for `List.Sort`, but the information holds true for `Table.Sort` too. I believe tables can be thought to be a list of records (although this is a simplification), hence why `x` and `y` are of type `record`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    add = Table.AddColumn(Source, "temp", each if [parentsku] = null then [sku] else [parentsku]),
    sort = Table.Sort(add,List.Transform({"temp", "parentsku"}, each {_, 0})),
    del = Table.RemoveColumns(sort,{"temp"})
in
    del
```

[image]